# Learning C - Pointers and memory addressing

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning C programming and I have a simple question about pointers...

I used the following code to play around with pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int * c;

printf("%x\n",c);
return 0;
}
```

When I print the value of C, I get back a 0. However, when I print &c (i.e. printf("&x\n",&c) I get an address in memory...

Shouldn't I be getting an address in memory when printing the pointer (i.e. printf("%x\n",c)?

--- **EDIT** ---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char * a = malloc(11);
    printf("String please\n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("%s",a);

}
```

The question is, why does printf("%s",a) returns the string instead of the address that is stored in a?

Shouldn't I use *a to follow the pointer and then print the string?

Comment: You have not initialized the pointer, so its value could be anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your current program is not correct. You define variable and do not set value before first use. the initial value is not guranteed for `c`, but you are lucky and it is equal to `0`. It means that `c` points to nowhere. when you print `&c` you print address of variable `c` itself. So actually both versions print address.

Comment: so, the pointer itself has an address in memory, which would be &c. And the pointer stores an address in itself, which would be c?

Comment: @alexBrand yes, every variable has an address, even if it is pointer. you can define pointer to pointer to int: `int **pc = &c;`

Comment: thanks a lot. So basically the pointer is initialized but its not pointing anywhere... Is this because of luck or it is automatically initialized to NULL?

Comment: @alexBrand it is not initialized, and it must be intialized by you before first use. no automatic initialization.

Comment: got into some trouble again... if you wouldn't mind check the new code I added. Thanks

Comment: @alexBrand it works that way because %s treats parameter as pointer to string and print string. if you use %x you will see the address

Answer (score 1):

printf is actually quite a complex function and can be made to do all sorts of tricks by giving it the right format specifier.

In your string example:

```
printf("%s", a)
```

the "%s" tells the printf function that the following variable should be treated as a string. In C, a string is a pointer to one or more char, terminated by a char containing 0. This is a pretty common request, which is why printf supports a format specifier "%s" that triggers this relatively complex behavior. If you want to print the address contained in the string pointer you have to use the format you found earlier:

```
printf("%x\n",a);
```

which tells printf to treat the contents of a as an unsigned integer, and print it in base 16.

*a would just be the value pointed to by a, which is just a single character.

You could print the single character with

```
printf("%c", *a);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. So basically printf figures out what you are trying to print, and will then decide if it should follow the pointer or not?

Comment: I'd add that C assumes that you known what you're doing, and won't try to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. For example:

int i = 10;
printf("%s", i);

That is, "declare an integer variable i, set it to 10, then print i treating as if it were a string"

This is valid C syntax and will compile without an error (though almost all modern compilers will issue a warning). When you try to run the program you'll get a segmentation fault, because 10 won't be a valid value for a memory address.

Answer (score 0):

Having int* c; If you print value of c, you get back a value that should be interpreted as a memory address of an integer value. In you example it might be 0 or something completely different as you are not initializing c.

If you print &c you get memory address of the pointer c (stored in stack).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int * c;
int a=10;
c = &a;

printf("%x\n",c);
return 0;
}
```

This may clarify what happens when you make the int pointer point to something in memory.